# Verb for logical sum

Tags: verbs, logic

If I perform the logical OR on two items, what am I doing? Ie. what's the verb for the logical sum?

Comment: Would this be better asked at [math.se]? Or in their [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics)?

Comment: The problem is that "logical" arithmetic isn't all that logical, to the layperson.  You either need to resort to mathematical notation or rephrase in "normal" language such as "either A or B or both".

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, most people would use **or** as a verb in this context.

*"To get the answer, I or-ed A with B."*

*"If we or A and B, we see that..."*

This makes sense because in this case **or** is an **operator**. I suppose the above are shortened versions of **use the or operator**:

*"To get the answer, I used the or operator on A and B."*

*"If we use the or operator on A and B, we see that..."*

**Edit:** Googling for sources to back me up leads me to the following duplicate questions:

[Should I use "ORing" or "OR'ing" when referring the verb of the Boolean logical operator "OR"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343653/should-i-use-oring-or-oring-when-referring-the-verb-of-the-boolean-logical)

[The verb for carrying out a bitwise OR/AND operation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79659/the-verb-for-carrying-out-a-bitwise-or-and-operation)

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical term is *inclusive disjunction* (or *alternation*). However, I wouldn't use either of these terms in a computer programming context. Stick to *logical OR*.

[Logical disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)

Comment: Yeah, I was just reading that article! But a "disjunction" sounds like it's separating something instead of combining it, which is also confirmed by the dictionary: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disjunction (the act of disconnecting or the state of being disconnected; separation).
But I like the word from set theory "union". I might go with the verb "unite".